# Instagram SERP Info not updating

Tags: search-results

When I search for my username on google, the details under my instagram link are not updated on any SERP including [google](https://google.com), [duckduckgo](https://duckduckgo.com) and [bing](https://bing.com). Is it not supposed to update once in a while? It's been months since I saw any update. Kindly help me understand this. Is there any way by which I can manually update this information.

It seems to me that this problem involves some sort of caching by Search engines. I want to update this info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check with your browser (menu > options > page details) that your update is effective.
Then I am afraid that you only can wait that search engine bots crawl your Instagram profile page again.

You don't update this page often and, don't be offended but, your profile is not a popular page, I mean, not often searched by search engine users. Thus, the crawl frequency must be very low for your profile page. I am not surprised that SERPs have not been updated after months. Keep watching from time to time.

Comment: Yeah. I know my page is not much popular. Haha! it's not something to get offended. I was wondering if there could be any tool to manually update it. Anyways. Thanks.